# Redirecting Console logs to a file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a batch file which in turn calls a python script(service). The script would always be running and would listen to port 8080 looking for API requests.

What I am trying to achieve is to redirect the API requests to a file.
I did try **Example.bat> test.txt 2>&1** . But the output is written to file only when I kill the script.

Is there a way to write the console logs to a file as soon as there is an API request?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to open the file and print the log on it. One way could be this:

```
logFile = open("/var/log/mylog", "w")
print("no changes", file = logFile)
```

But, in python 3 or higher, it's easier!

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("/var/log/mylog", "w")
print ("no changes")
```

It will redirect globally your print statements.

Comment: thank you for the response.. will try implementing this solution and will post back!

Comment: hope it helps you